# Google Direction API -REQUEST_DENIED

Tags: android, google-maps-android-api-2, google-directions-api

I am totally frustrated - I have a simple android app and I tried to get the direction using the google maps directions API after rendering the map . The XML response I get is REQUEST_DENIED.

Please help!!!. I am not an expert in android and still learning the tricks... This is the hptts request that goes out:-

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?origin=losgatos&destination=cupertino&sensor=false

I had posted this question earlier too but didn't get any response. 
thanks in advance..

My full code:-
( Main class).

```
public class MainActivity extends FragmentActivity {
MapDirection md ;
LatLng fromPosition;
LatLng toPosition;
ArrayList<LatLng>ToFrom;
Document doc;
ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint;
PolylineOptions rectLine;
//Intent MapProcessIntent;
ArrayList<LatLng> markerpoints;
LocationManager lm;
GoogleMap map;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //setContentView(R.layout.main);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    markerpoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();

    lm = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
    //LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
    boolean enabled = lm.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
    Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
   criteria.setAccuracy(Criteria.ACCURACY_FINE);
   criteria.setAltitudeRequired(false);
   criteria.setBearingRequired(false);
   criteria.setCostAllowed(true);
   criteria.setPowerRequirement(Criteria.POWER_HIGH);
   String provider = lm.getBestProvider(criteria, true);
   Location currentLocation = lm.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

   SupportMapFragment fm =(SupportMapFragment)this.getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map);
    map = fm.getMap();
    if  (map != null){
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true); 
        CameraPosition cameraPosition= new CameraPosition.Builder().target(new LatLng(currentLocation.getLatitude(), 
                currentLocation.getLongitude())).zoom(13).build();
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));   

    }

    LatLng fromPosition = new LatLng(37.258507,-121.967533);
    LatLng toPosition = new LatLng(37.236064,-121.961595);
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(fromPosition).title("Start"));
    map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(toPosition).title("End"));




    //TextView textview = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.mainstring);
    //textview.setText("making the web service call..");



    //fromPosition = new LatLng(37.258507,-121.967533);
    //toPosition = new LatLng(37.236064,-121.961595);   
    ToFrom = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    ToFrom.add(fromPosition);
    ToFrom.add(toPosition);
    //MapProcessIntent = new Intent(this, MapProcess.class);
    //Document doc = md.getDocument(fromPosition, toPosition, MapDirection.MODE_DRIVING);
    /*if (doc.hasChildNodes()== true)
    {
        System.out.println("This document has child nodes..");
    }
    if (doc != null){   
    //ArrayList<LatLng> directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);  
    //PolylineOptions rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);

    for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
    rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
    }*/
    MakeWebCall mwc = new MakeWebCall();
    mwc.execute(ToFrom);


}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
    return true;
}



 private class MakeWebCall extends AsyncTask<ArrayList<LatLng>, Void, Document>
 {

 @Override
 protected Document doInBackground(ArrayList<LatLng>...list ) {
       Document d = null;
       LatLng From = (LatLng)list[0].get(0);
       LatLng To= (LatLng)list[0].get(1);
     // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the list 
     try {
         md= new MapDirection();
         d = md.getDocument(From, To, MapDirection.MODE_DRIVING);


     } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(" Some error "+ e.getMessage());

     }
     return d;
  }
 // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
 @Override
 protected void onPostExecute(Document doc) {
     if ( doc !=null){
         directionPoint = md.getDirection(doc);
         if ( directionPoint.isEmpty()== false){
             rectLine = new PolylineOptions().width(3).color(Color.RED);
             for(int i = 0 ; i < directionPoint.size() ; i++) {          
                rectLine.add(directionPoint.get(i));
             }

             if ( rectLine !=null){
                    Polyline pl= map.addPolyline(rectLine);
                    if ( pl != null){
                        pl.setVisible(true);
                        System.out.println(" I GOT IT");
                    }
             //String polylineStr = "POLYLINE";

                //MapProcessIntent.putExtra(polylineStr, rectLine);
                //startActivity(MapProcessIntent);
         }
     }
     else
     {
         System.out.println(" document is empty");
     }


 }
 }
 }
 }
```

My MapDirection file ( which does the web service call :)

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;

import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.ClientProtocolException;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.protocol.BasicHttpContext;
import org.apache.http.protocol.HttpContext;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
import org.xml.sax.SAXParseException;



import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;

class MapDirection {
public final static String MODE_DRIVING = "driving";
public final static String MODE_WALKING = "walking";

public MapDirection() { }

 public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

    try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        String hosturl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?";
        String newstring = "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
        + "&destination=" + end.latitude + ","+ end.longitude + "&sensor=true";
        //37.255666,-121.967683
        //37.258507,-121.967533
        //String newstring = "origin=37.2345487,-121.5840723&destination=37.236064,-121.961595&sensor=true";
        String newurl = URLEncoder.encode(newstring, "UTF-8");
        String finalurl = hosturl + newurl;
        System.out.println("web service call: "+finalurl);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(finalurl);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        System.out.println(" Returned valid document");
        return doc;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException e) {

        System.out.println(" Web service returned IllegalArgumentException:"+ e.getMessage());
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch(IOException f){
        System.out.println(" Web service returned IOException:"+ f.getMessage());
        f.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch(IllegalStateException g){
        System.out.println(" Web service returned IllegalStateException:"+ g.getMessage());
        g.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch(ParserConfigurationException h){
        System.out.println(" Web service returned ParserConfigurationException:"+ h.getMessage());
        h.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
    catch(SAXException i){
        System.out.println(" Web service returned SAXException:"+ i.getMessage());
        i.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }

}

public String getDurationText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DurationText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDurationValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("duration");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DurationValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getDistanceText (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "text"));
    Log.i("DistanceText", node2.getTextContent());
    return node2.getTextContent();
}

public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}

public String getStartAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("start_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getEndAddress (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("end_address");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("StartAddress", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public String getCopyRights (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("copyrights");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    Log.i("CopyRights", node1.getTextContent());
    return node1.getTextContent();
}

public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3,statusList;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    statusList = doc.getElementsByTagName("status");
    if (statusList.getLength()> 0){
        System.out.println(" Status result of XML response for direction  API:"+statusList.item(0).getTextContent());
    }
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}

private int getNodeIndex(NodeList nl, String nodename) {
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nl.getLength() ; i++) {
        if(nl.item(i).getNodeName().equals(nodename))
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}

private ArrayList<LatLng> decodePoly(String encoded) {
    ArrayList<LatLng> poly = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    int index = 0, len = encoded.length();
    int lat = 0, lng = 0;
    while (index < len) {
        int b, shift = 0, result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlat = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lat += dlat;
        shift = 0;
        result = 0;
        do {
            b = encoded.charAt(index++) - 63;
            result |= (b & 0x1f) << shift;
            shift += 5;
        } while (b >= 0x20);
        int dlng = ((result & 1) != 0 ? ~(result >> 1) : (result >> 1));
        lng += dlng;

        LatLng position = new LatLng((double) lat / 1E5, (double) lng / 1E5);
        poly.add(position);
    }
    return poly;
}
}
```

Let me post my manifest file too..

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.menonmatics.mapapplication"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" >

<uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="9"
    android:targetSdkVersion="16" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
 <permission
    android:name="com.menonmatics.mapapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"
    android:protectionLevel="signature" />
<uses-permission    android:name="com.menonmatics.mapapplication.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
<uses-permission     android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>

<uses-feature
    android:glEsVersion="0x00020000"
    android:required="true"/>
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
    <activity
        android:name="com.menonmatics.mapapplication.MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".MapProcess"
 android:label="Map Rendering">
<intent-filter>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
</intent-filter>
</activity> 
    <meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="<tooitout"/>
</application>

</manifest>
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Check out this example [google direction](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/drawing-driving-route-directions-between-two-locations-using-google-directions-in-google-map-android-api-v2/)

try this:

```
try {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new  StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        String hosturl="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?";
        String newstring = "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude 
        + "&destination=" + end.latitude + ","+ end.longitude + "&sensor=true";
        //37.255666,-121.967683
        //37.258507,-121.967533
        //String newstring = "origin=37.2345487,-121.5840723&destination=37.236064,-121.961595&sensor=true";
        //String newurl = URLEncoder.encode(newstring, "UTF-8");
        String finalurl = hosturl + newstring;
        System.out.println("web service call: "+finalurl);
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(finalurl);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        System.out.println(" Returned valid document");
        return doc;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks Srikanth. appreciate your prompt response.  what is wrong with the following code I wrote:-

Comment: do I really need to use google places API?. Can't I just directly use the web-services call and parse the xml response. I am using the old google map API which had not been integrated with places. Is there a compatibility issue btw the direction webservices and the google map api I am using resulting in REQUEST_DENIED?.

Comment: i'm not sure about that sunny i tried only direction api regarding webservice yes u can u just have to pass the start and end lat/lng to the parser in the above example

Comment: i was replying to another thread on the same issue. I rewrote the full code using google Map API v2 and put my web service call into the background as mentioned in the link. I also have the key for my android app from the API console. added that to my manifest file. still my XML comes back empty after "direction response". what I have also noticed is that though the webservice call is being made in background, android sends out multiple identical requests one after the other. any tips - I am so frustrated!! any ideas or tips Srikanth?

Comment: there are only 2 files - mainactivity and MapDirection. nothing fancy. Only one activity. pretty simple. MapDirection contains exact code base from the link you provided. I added little extra to look for status check etc.

Comment: edited.. if answered please don't forgot u accept the answer :)

Comment: Srikanth, it worked!.. thanks. u mean URL encoding was not required at all!!. funny thing is that I tried it first without it and it never worked. so i moved it to urlencoding. but it never worked.. i moved on to other tries such as  ansyc background thread etc.. can u please tell what caused it?

Comment: the Encoded URL was not proper...so i just changed it :) glad it worked :)